# Database going to Suspect mode

Tags: sql-server, corruption

I have a frequent problem, that is one of my databases goes to suspect mode.

Many times I have recovered it with:

```
ALTER DATABASE Your_Db SET EMERGENCY
DBCC checkdb('Your_Db')
ALTER DATABASE Your_Db SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
DBCC CheckDB ('Your_Db', REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)
ALTER DATABASE Your_Db SET MULTI_USER
```

It continues to become suspect after. Please provide me the permanent solution.

Comment: Most likely you have a hardware fault. Move to a different server before you lose the database permanently.

Comment: I conur with Mark here it seems a hardware issue. Instead of running repair queries first try to find out cause. look into errorlog and eventviewer for more information about error. Get you SAN team involved ask them to have a look at SAN controllers and connectors.

Comment: Check the Windows service and application logs - SQL Server may be noting in there what caused the switch to "suspect", or at least may record in there exactly when it happened so you can look for errors from elsewhere around the same time that might indicate a particular hardware/driver/other issue.

Answer (score 3):

> It continues to become suspect after. Please provide me the permanent
>   solution.

The permanent solution is to figure out WHY/WHAT is causing the database to go suspect. Is it a filter drivers, bad hardware, etc. We don't know and can't tell you, this is something you'll need to inspect on your own. You'll want to get your sysadmins involved as well.

> Many times I have recovered it with: ALTER DATABASE Your_Db SET
>   EMERGENCY DBCC checkdb('Your_Db') ALTER DATABASE Your_Db SET
>   SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE DBCC CheckDB ('Your_Db',
>   REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS) ALTER DATABASE Your_Db SET MULTI_USER

Please, don't ever use this as the first line to attack - unless you don't like your job and are looking elsewhere for employment.

Check to see what is being corrupted, how bad it is, the extent. If you aren't sure, hire a consultant that specializes in corruption.

Comment: Exactly: wherever possible don't "just recover" without trying to work out what the source of the problem is, that way you risk exacerbating the situation.